# build opencv for java on rpi4

Tags: opencv, java

I'm trying to build `OpencCV` for `Java` on raspberry pi 4B. I am quite new in this sphere and do not understand almost everything. At first, I just wanted to unload my `.jar` file to the raspberry and run it there. This `.jar` file is a compiled project in which the `OpenCV` library is used. As I understand it, just using `OpenCV` library in your project is not enough and you also need to install `OpenCV` on the raspberry itself. I found two articles on how to build it on a raspberry [First one](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2018/12/18/cross-compile-opencv-raspberry-pi-raspbian/)  and [Second one](https://robinhenniges.com/part-1-installing-opencv-3-1-0-on-raspberry-pi-debian-jessy-with-java-library/). I have tried to build `OpenCV` by following the second article and built it. But I have got only `libopencv_java440.so` file without other files (like `libopencv_core.so`). But anyway I have tried to run my program and tried to save an image from camera placed on raspberry, but got only a strange image (colored stripes). After this I have tried to run my `Python` program on raspberry and it worked fine.
Then I have tried the first article but into `cmake` I also included this lines from the second article `-D JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/include -D JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/libawt.so -D JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/arm/server/libjvm.so`. After this everything built and I got all the files that were missing before, but now I have lost `libopencv_java440.so` file.
This is as awful as possible, because I also ran into a lot of errors just doing `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. And the question itself - How can I use `OpenCV` from `Java` on raspberry pi? What should be installed and how should it be installed? Are there any articles about this somewhere? Thanks for any advice and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And again I answer my own question. This is quite strange community, it's not like `SOF` where everyone know the solution and can help you. So about the solution. As you could see I had a problem when I built `OpenCV` by following the first article I didn't get the `libopencv_java440.so` file. **But** I can get it after building `OpenCV` like in the second article! So in my java code:

```java
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_core.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_img_hash.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_photo.so");

System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_xphoto.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_flann.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_features2d.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_structured_light.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so");

System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_video.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_ximgproc.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_aruco.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_bgsegm.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_bioinspired.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_face.so");

System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_dnn.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_tracking.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_plot.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_ml.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_ml.so");
System.load("/opt/opencv-4.4.0/lib/libopencv_text.so");
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

I load `.so` files from the first build. But how do `java` understands which `Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME` I want to load? It is simple - when I run my `.jar` file on raspberry I pass an argument:
`-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/share/java/opencv4/`. So this is the solution. But for the first time it didn't work for me and gave some strange errors. Raspberry could detect my camera but couldn't get an image from it, but then I have changed the camera to another one and it started working. So the code that I used to test camera:

```java
VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);

if (camera.isOpened())
{
    System.out.println("Video is captured");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Camera isn't opened");
}
Mat mat = new Mat();
while (!camera.read(mat)) {}
Imgcodecs imageCodecs = new Imgcodecs(); 
imageCodecs.imwrite("/home/pi/testt.jpg", mat);
System.out.println("Image saved");
```

And here it is, this is the solution!